# Increase to X% or increase by X%?

Tags: grammar

Referring to the tuna fishing quota:

> 今年より約５２％多くなります。  (from a news article)
>   今年より約５２％増える。  (made up by me)
>   (This) will increase by around 52% compared to this year.

Is there any difference in meaning/feeling between the above two sentences?

How would I say increase **to** X% rather than increase **by** X%? Is it just from context? Would the following be correct:

> フォークの生産はtotal outputの５０%増える
>   Production of forks will increase **to** 50% of total output.

(sorry, I don't know how to say 'total output')

But if I just said:

> フォークの生産は５０%増える

Would that mean **to** 50% or **by** 50% or is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 今年より約５２％多くなります。 (from a news article)
>
> 今年より約５２％増える。 (made up by me)
>
> Is there any difference in meaning/feeling between the above two sentences?

No, not really.  The first one sounds just a little politer for using 「ます」, but that is about it. If you wanted to use a big kanji word, that would be 「増加{ぞうか}する」.

> How would I say increase **to** X% rather than increase **by** X%? Is it just from context? Would the following be correct:
>
> フォークの生産はtotal outputの５０%増える
>
> Production of forks will increase to 50% of total output.

No, that will not work.  「50％増える」 **always** means "to increase **by** 50%".

To say "to increase **to** 50%", you need to say:

> 「50％(**に or にまで**)増える」

Particles are everything.  To describe a move/change from A to B, you usually must use a に or へ.  Increases and decreases (from A to B) are no exceptions.

> フォークの生産は５０%増える
>
> Would that mean **to 50%** or **by 50%** or is it ambiguous?

It can only mean "**by** 50%".  It is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "the production of forks is estimated to account for 50% of the total output"
(フォークの生産は、総生産量の50%を占める見込みです。）, it should be "フォークの生産は総生産量の５０%に上昇する/に増える"(The production of forks will rise to 50% of the total output.).